# Find y-value given x-value on a beta distribution

Tags: r, interpolation

I am trying to find the y-values of points on a beta curve.

This is my beta; let's say I would like to find the point whose x-value is 0.6, for example:

```
x=seq(0,1,length=100)
y=dbeta(x,7,2)
plot(x,y, type="l", col="blue")
abline(v=0.6)
```

[image]

I have tried to add the corresponding point, but for some reason it does not work:

```
points(0.6, beta(7, 2), cex=3, pch=20, col="black")
```

[image]

Once fixed this problem, how can I find the y-value?
I looked online; I found some examples using approxfun but I don't know how to apply it to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `dbeta()` instead of `beta()` (assuming that's not a typo), and specify all three of `x`, `shape1`, and `shape2`. I think you want

```
points(0.6, dbeta(0.6, shape1=7, shape2=2), 
   cex=3, pch=20, col="black")
```

If you want to store the actual y-value in a variable, use

```
bval <- dbeta(0.6, shape1=7, shape2=2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how can I find the y-value for that point?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes, it worked. I just wonder how to go from there. Once I run the "points" code, how to extract the coordinates?

Comment: Saw it now. Thanks again!